# Can't create table - mysql

Tags: mysql

during an import of an sql file I got this message.

> errno: 121 "Duplicate key on write or update"

The code is:

```
CREATE TABLE `llx_prelevement_facture` (
  `rowid` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `fk_facture` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fk_prelevement_lignes` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`rowid`),
  KEY `idx_prelevement_facture_fk_prelevement_lignes` (`fk_prelevement_lignes`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_prelevement_facture_fk_prelevement_lignes` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_prelevement_lignes`) REFERENCES `llx_prelevement_lignes` (`rowid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Anyone a helping hand to fix this?

Comment: seems to be an inconsistence data.